# Sort nodes after using getElementsByTagName by the nodes attributes

Tags: python, sorting, attributes, minidom

**EDIT**

The dictionary is the offender here, the answer marked on this question works, the dictionary does what it wants though. Sorting the dictionary is the answer in this case, but now I know how to sort nodes via attributes and so do you.

**END**

I am so happy to be asking Python questions, here is what I have:

```
def parse_fixed_data(self, format):
    return_message = {}
    nodes = format.getElementsByTagName('data')
    for node in nodes:
        return_message[node.attributes['name'].value] = self.raw_message[int(node.attributes['from'].value):int(node.attributes['to'].value)] 
    return return_message
```

This works almost beautifully. The 'format' variable is an already parsed node, which contains a bunch of 'data' nodes. Here is the xml:

```
<pmbmsg id='pmb_header'>
    <version maj='01' min='00' rev='0000' type='FIXED' delimeter=''>
        <data seq='1'   from='0'   to='3'    name='message_type'/>
        <data seq='2'   from='3'   to='13'   name='version'/>
        <data seq='3'   from='13'  to='33'   name='from_system'/>
        <data seq='4'   from='33'  to='53'   name='to_system'/>
        <data seq='5'   from='53'  to='73'   name='family'/>
        <data seq='6'   from='73'  to='83'   name='priority'/>
        <data seq='7'   from='83'  to='103'  name='msg_format_id'/>
        <data seq='8'   from='103' to='135'  name='msg_unique_id'/>
        <data seq='9'   from='135' to='161'  name='created'/>
        <data seq='10'  from='161' to='163'  name='hop_count'/>
        <data seq='11'  from='163' to='173'  name='original_msg_format_id'/>
        <data seq='12'  from='173' to='205'  name='original_unique_id'/>
        <data seq='13'  from='205' to='245'  name='padding'/>
        <data seq='14'  from='245' to='4086' name='message_data'/>
    </version>
</pmbmsg>
```

Well this works all well and good but I get the dictionary elements back in this order:

```
u'to_system'            
u'padding'          
u'original_msg_format_id'   
u'original_unique_id'       
u'family'           
u'created'          
u'msg_format_id'        
u'hop_count'            
u'msg_unique_id'            
u'priority'         
u'version'          
u'from_system'          
u'message_type'         
u'message_data'
```

(values removed)

I would like them to come back in the order they appear in the xml, and there seq attribute could help this. After this line in the Python code:

```
nodes = format.getElementsByTagName('data')
```

...is there some function I could run on nodes that would sort this? Or is there something I could state when getting the nodes that would let it know to sort them? You would think that it would just naturally get it in the order the xml is written?

If there is no function to do this auto-magically for me, I can handle hacking it.

Comment: You need to sort a dictionary by value.  Take a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value.  Or do not use a dictionary.

Comment: There is no room in my dictionary for the sequence number. My question is about sorting nodes by their attributes, not sorting dictionaries, that is easy, and if push comes to shove I'll hack something around to do that, but I was wondering if you could get the nodes from getElementsByTagName sorted, not the dictionary.

Comment: @KacieHouser At quick glance I thought they were not sorted because of the dictionary.  I use element tree for my python xml needs. I am unsure how the dom implementation works.

Comment: @eat_a_lemon does element tree have the feature I am looking for?

Comment: @KacieHouser I am fairly certain element tree will return the values in the order that they are in the document

Comment: @eat_a_lemon turns out it does do it in the order the xml is defined, see the edit on the question. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nodes are not sorted by the name in the XML, and also this is reflected in the list of nodes. They are going to appear in the same order from which they were iterated. Lists, by definition, are ordered. Dictionaries are not. The problem you're having is that when you're iterating the dictionary keys, your attribute names are out of order and there is no way around this short of sorting the dictionary.

You can either sort the nodes before processing the dict (which still does not guarantee that the dict itself will be ordered):

```
>>> [node.attributes['name'].value for node in sorted(nodes, key=lambda x: x.attributes['name'].value)]
[u'created', u'family', u'from_system', u'hop_count', 
u'message_data', u'message_type', u'msg_format_id', u'msg_unique_id', 
u'original_msg_format_id', u'original_unique_id', u'padding', u'priority', 
u'to_system', u'version']
```

Or you can use [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (available in Python 2.7+) instead of a normal dictionary to create `return_message`.

```
# No example because I don't have acces to Python 2.7
```

Or you can sort your dictionary by values using [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted).

```
>>> import operator
>>> sorted_return_message = sorted(return_message.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
>>> for k,v in sorted_return_message: print k
... 
created
family
from_system
hop_count
message_data
message_type
msg_format_id
msg_unique_id
original_msg_format_id
original_unique_id
padding
priority
to_system
version
```

Or you can just sort the keys at runtime:

```
>>> for k in sorted(return_message):
...     print k
... 
created
family
from_system
hop_count
message_data
message_type
msg_format_id
msg_unique_id
original_msg_format_id
original_unique_id
padding
priority
to_system
version
```

Comment: I actually want them sorted by the 'seq' attribute, but this enough for me to get what I need I think. Thank you, it is good to know that the dict may have a mind of it's own. You would think the dict would put the first key => value assignment at the top, the second under that and so on, we shall see.

Comment: Yeah it can be confusing at first, but that's why they added the `OrderedDict` object in Python 2.7.  From diveintopython.org "Dictionaries have no concept of order among elements. It is incorrect to say that the elements are “out of order”; they are simply unordered. This is an important distinction which will annoy you when you want to access the elements of a dictionary in a specific, repeatable order (like alphabetical order by key). There are ways of doing this, they're just not built into the dictionary."

Comment: HA I was just reading that, the dictionary was the culprit, your code is clever though and I may find it useful, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 2.7 , OrderedDict is a new feature

Comment: I am running like 2.4, and again, it's not the Dictionary I am looking to order, I don't have the key to order in the dictionary. I would like to sort the nodes in the xml by their attributes.